# Unable to change QML ListView default move transition

Tags: qt, listview, animation, qml, qlistview

I have this pretty simple ListView which consists of a few squares. All squares are shown in the viewport at all times. Arrow keys and mouse click can navigate between the squares.

```
Item {
    id: container
    Layout.fillHeight: true // (Is a Layout child)
    Layout.fillWidth: true

    Component {
        id: listComponent
        Item {
            height: 100
            width: 100
            Rectangle {
                id: square
                anchors.fill: parent
                color: "pink"
                opacity: 0.5

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        list.currentIndex = index
                    }
                }

                states: [
                    State {
                        name: "active"
                        when: list.currentIndex == index
                        PropertyChanges { target: square; opacity: 1 }
                    }
                ]
                transitions: Transition {
                    NumberAnimation { properties: "opacity"; duration: 300}
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: list
        delegate: listComponent
        model: 5
        currentIndex: 0

        anchors.centerIn: parent
        displayMarginEnd: 100 * 5
        displayMarginBeginning: 100 * 5
        spacing: 100 * 0.2
        transform: Translate { x: - 100 / 2 }
        focus: true
        keyNavigationEnabled: true
    }
}
```

It's easy to transition the opacity between active/inactive items, but it *seems to be impossible to change the moving transition*. Documentation says I should use [move](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#move-prop) and [moveDisplaced](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#moveDisplaced-prop) for exactly this, but I tried those and also [displaced](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#displaced-prop) (for any trigger) but nothing changes. They seem to have absolutely no effect.

The default transitional behavior is weird. If you notice navigating in the "positive" direction, as in increasing the item index, is very smooth, but when reversing the moving transition the easing is different and kind of abrupt.
**I would like to have the position transition of both directions be equally smooth**.

Comment: I see nor `move` neither `moveDisplaced` transitions in your code. please provide [mcve]

Comment: What should move here? Your model is static and there are no rows moving that could be animated.

Comment: There's no reason to use any of the mentioned functions when the above code is a completely reproducible example...
The model is static yes, the actual view is not. Notice how the ListView itself has a certain dimension and how the sum of all its delegates does not fit this dimension. ListView will by default clip the delegates that don't fit and bring them into view when navigating the list. Be it by flicking (default), mouse or keys if the latter are provided. I use displayMarginEnd/Beginning here to show all delegates anyways but still have the transition effect.

Comment: Yes, those animation hooks are for model changes, you found another solution for what you want "This property holds the transition to apply to items in the view that are being moved due to a move operation in the view's model."

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld You're apparently referring to "move" and that I should use it, are you not? I know about these properties and what they are supposed to do. I also tried to use them with the original code. It did not affect the animation in *any* way. Do I misunderstand your comment?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I did not set a width in my original code, even when I mentioned it in the comments. It makes all the difference. See this simplified example:

```
    // EXAMPLE LISTVIEW
    Component {
        id: listComp
        Rectangle {
            id: listRect
            height: 100                     // The actual dimension of our list items:
            width: 100                      // Squares
            color: "grey"
            opacity: 0.5                    // Opacity is not required for demonstration purposes but makes it easier to visualize
            states: [
                State {
                    name: "active"
                    when: listview.currentIndex == index
                    PropertyChanges { target: listRect; opacity: 1 }
                }
            ]
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    listview.currentIndex = index
                }
            }
            transitions: Transition {
                NumberAnimation { property: "opacity"; duration: 300 }
            }                
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: listview
        model: 10                           // Make ten squares, each 100 wide, equals 1000
        delegate: listComp
        width: 100                          // The fix...!
        keyNavigationEnabled: true
        focus: true
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal    // to fit the screen better
    }
```

When navigating through this list with keys or mouse, the displacement will be transitioned automatically to bring the next index into view.

If *no* explicit dimension is provided for the ListView itself in this example, or a dimension smaller than one delegate, it will show exactly one delegate (the currentIndex) and the previous one (none when it's the first in the list).

When increasing the index (moving to the next item that is) the animation appears to be rather smooth, for one can see the previous delegate being moved as well. When decreasing the index (moving to the previous item) the animation appears visually cut of, for the next item is not shown and neither is its displacement.
This makes for a visually cut off effect.

**As soon as you provide a dimension for ListView that fits at least one delegate's dimension, both the previous and the next item are shown and the transition appears to be smooth in both directions.**
*Depending on the orientation this could be either only width for horizontal or height for vertical.*

Interestingly enough even when adding "overflow" so to say in form of displayMarginEnd (which will show the next upcoming items if you increase it above one delegates dimension) the animation still gets cut off. (This is what I experienced in my original post)

(Apparently as soon as you make the ListView bigger than the sum of all delegates, there's nothing to move to begin with.)

See this visual comparison for comprehension and play around with the ListView width from this example to reproduce:
[image]
[image]